# How to include this slider navigation menu in jquery mobile theme?

Tags: jquery, mobile, include, navigation, slider

How to include the slider navigation of the theme below in jquery mobile framework?

slider navigation bar of this:
http://indiqo.eu/demos/hotcake/

I want to include that slider the same way on the top of the navigation
under header section

```
<aside>

    <!-- Main Navigation -->
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li class="active"><a href="index.htm" title="Home">Home</a></li>
            <!-- Use <span> in order to display a count -->
            <li><a href="blog.htm" title="Blog">Blog <span>8</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="page.htm" title="Page">Page</a></li>
            <li><a href="twitter.htm" title="Twitter Feed">Twitter Feed</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.htm" title="Contact Form">Contact Form</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <!-- Newsletter Subscription -->
    <section id="newsletter">
        <h2>Newsletter</h2>
        <!-- Make sure to add a working action and method -->
        <form action="http://indiqo.eu/demos/hotcake/index.htm" method="post">
            <div>
                <label for="newsletter-input">Subscribe to our weekly newsletter</label>
                <input name="email" id="newsletter-input" />
                <input type="image" src="images/icons/icon-subscribe.png" alt="Subscribe" id="newsletter-submit" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </section>

    <!-- Social Media -->
    <section id="socialize">
        <h2>Socialize</h2>
        <ul>
            <li class="twitter"><a href="http://twitter.com/indiqo" title="Twitter">twitter.com/indiqo</a></li>
            <li class="facebook"><a href="http://facebook.com/bartel" title="Facebook">facebook.com/bartel</a></li>
            <li class="flickr"><a href="http://flickr.com/photos/indiqomedia" title="Flickr">flickr.com/photos/indiqomedia</a></li>
            <li class="linkedin"><a href="http://linkedin.com/in/indiqo" title="LinkedIn">linkedin.com/in/indiqo</a></li>
            <li class="forrst"><a href="http://forr.st/-indiqo" title="Forrst">forr.st/-indiqo</a></li>
        </ul>
    </section>

    <!-- Contact Information -->
    <section id="contact">
        <h2>Get in Touch</h2>
        <ul>
            <li class="web"><a href="http://indiqo.eu/" title="Website">indiqo.eu</a></li>
            <li class="email"><a href="mailto:hello@indiqo.eu" title="E-Mail">hello@indiqo.eu</a></li>
            <li class="phone"><a href="tel:+4951819313356" title="Phone">+49 5181 9313356</a></li>
            <li class="address">
                <div>
                    <b>Street Name</b><br />
                    ZIP Code + City<br />
                    Country
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </section>

</aside>
```

I want to include in a same way in jquery mobile. How to go about it?